# Adding multiple items to a combo box using AddRange

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, combobox, addrange

Baically I'm looking for something like this...

```
cbo_Genre.Items.AddRange({"Horror", "Comedy"});
```

Comment: what would be wrong with either cbo_Genre.Items = new List<string>(new string[] {"Horror", "Comedy"}); or cbo_Genre.Items = (new string[]{"Horror", "Comedy"});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this.

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"Typical", "Compact", "Custom"});
cbo_Genre.Items.AddRange(new string[]{"Horror", "Comedy"});
```

`AddRange` adds an array of items to the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like

```
cbo_Genre.Items.AddRange(new string[] {"Horror", "Comedy"});
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in C# 4.0, using an implicitly typed array:

```
cbo_Genre.Items.AddRange(new[] {"Horror", "Comedy"});
```